# Mathquill how to write formula into pdf file

Tags: javascript, html, mathquill

I'm trying to create a webpage where users are able to write formulas (rendered by mathquill).
This is the code:

```
      createButton(document.body, 
    function()
    {
    var para1 = parent.frame1.document.createElement("p");
    para1.setAttribute("id","Line"+i.toString());
    var t1 = parent.frame1.document.createTextNode("Line "+i.toString()+":");
    para1.appendChild(t1);
    parent.frame1.document.body.appendChild(para1);

    var para = parent.frame1.document.createElement("p");
    para.setAttribute("id","math"+i.toString());
    para.setAttribute("class", "mq-math-mode");
    var t = parent.frame1.document.createTextNode("");
    para.appendChild(t);
    parent.frame1.document.body.appendChild(para);  

    latex = $('#basic-latex').on('keydown keypress', function() {
          var prev = latex.val();
          setTimeout(function() {
            var now = latex.val();
            if (now !== prev) mq.latex(now);
          });
        });

    mq = MQ.MathField(para, {
          autoSubscriptNumerals: true,
          handlers: { edit: function() {
            if (!latex.is(':focus')) latex.val(mq.latex());
          } }
        });
        //latex.val(mq.latex());

    //mathField = MQ.MathField(para, {spaceBehavesLikeTab: true});
    i = i+1;
    }
, "Create new line");
```

Then, I would like to save formulas in a pdf file.
I'm using the package jsPDF, but I'm not able to write the rendered formulas in the pdf. Is anybody able to help me?

Thanks a lot in advance

I add the code to create the PDF.

```
       var doc = new jsPDF();
       var str = mq.latex();
       var src = 'http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?'+str
       var som = new Image();
       som.src = src;
       var imgData = 'data:image/png;base64,'+ Base64.encode(som);
       doc.addImage(imgData, 'png', 10, 50);
       doc.save('Test.pdf');
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, the code snippet you're showing works fine, it's some usage of jsPDF that doesn't work, right? Can you explain more about how you're trying to use jsPDF?

Comment: I'm using jsPDF because I need to create a pdf file with all the content of html created by the user. In other words, the user writes formulas, which is rendered by mathquill. Then I would like that all the user wrote is saved in the pdf file as it appears to the user.

Comment: Can you post an example page, or at least a code snippet, where you try to use jsPDF to write the rendered formulas in the PDF, but you are not able to?

Comment: Please read the code I added in my question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you checked the output of `Base64.encode(som)`? Looks like this won't work due to a CORS issue, but if that's the problem, it can be workarounded.